# Prop is missing and the compiler does not complain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to create [Elevate App Bar](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#elevate-app-bar) as the following:

```
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactElement;
}

function ElevationScroll({ children }: Props) {
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: 0
  });

  return React.cloneElement(children, {
    elevation: trigger ? 4 : 0
  });
}

export function ElevateAppBar(props: Props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <ElevationScroll {...props}>
        <AppBar>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6">Scroll to Elevate App Bar</Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </ElevationScroll>
      <Toolbar />
      <Container>
        <Box my={2}>
          {[...new Array(120)]
            .map(
              () => `Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.
Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.`
            )
            .join("\n")}
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

the component is used in the `index.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ElevateAppBar } from "./demo";

ReactDOM.render(<ElevateAppBar />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

`ElevateAppBar` expects `prop` and I did not pass any. However I expect that the compiler will complain, but it does not. Why?

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-0r0of

Comment: without modifying any thing it raises the error [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/wLlOlRB.jpg)

Comment: why it compiles and executes? It should not get executed.

Comment: Yes you're right I focused only on th editor warning